# Display Action labes in single row instead of combobox in grid on admin side magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to show Display Action labes in single row instead of combobox in grid on admin side magento .My code for combobox is

```
$this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    =>  Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '100',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Edit'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    ),               
           array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Delete'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/delete'),
            'confirm'  => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Are you sure?'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    ),
             array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('View'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/view'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    )
             ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));
```

See image for combobox style.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this code

```
$this->addColumn('actions', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('adminnotification')->__('Actions'),
    'width'     => '250px',
    'sortable'  => false,
    'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/notification_grid_renderer_actions',
));
```

under class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Notification_Grid`
and also see the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Notification_Grid_Renderer_Actions`

If you have still any problem let me know.